# Add vertex to framed graph in OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

I am not sure if this is an issue with OrientDB or operator error. In the code below, I am expecting to create new instances of Person, however, the new vertices are not going in as Person objects, rather they end up in the "V" collection.

This has been partially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848565/tinkerpop-frames-writing-to-database-newbie), however this was using TinkerGraph where I am using OrientGraph. According to a comment in the linked page, I believe what I have done should work. Is there something I am missing?

```
package simpleFrames;

import com.tinkerpop.frames.Property;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.VertexFrame;

public interface Person extends VertexFrame {

    @Property("firstName")
    public void setFirstName(String name);

    @Property("firstName")
    public String getFirstName();

}
```

.

```
package simpleFrames;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OType;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphNoTx;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertexType;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.FramedGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.FramedGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.modules.javahandler.JavaHandlerModule;

public class go {

    static String remote = "localhost";
    static String database = "muck";
    static String username = "admin";
    static String password = "admin";
    static String rootPassword = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String location = String.format("remote:%s", remote);
        String fullDatabaseName = String.format("%s/%s", location, database);

        OServerAdmin admin = new OServerAdmin(location);
        try {
            admin.connect("root", rootPassword);
            admin.createDatabase(fullDatabaseName, "graph", "memory");

        } finally {
            admin.close();
        }

        OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(fullDatabaseName, username, password);
        try {
            OrientGraphNoTx noTx = factory.getNoTx();
            try {
                OrientVertexType person = noTx.createVertexType("Person");
                person.createProperty("firstName", OType.STRING);

                noTx.commit();

            } finally {
                noTx.shutdown();
            }

            OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();
            try {
                FramedGraph<OrientGraph> framedGraph = new FramedGraphFactory(new JavaHandlerModule()).create(graph);

                Person mark = framedGraph.addVertex(null, Person.class);
                mark.setFirstName("Mark");

                Person frank = framedGraph.addVertex(null, Person.class);
                frank.setFirstName("Frank");

                graph.commit();

                /* Records are going in as V */
                for (Vertex v : graph.getVerticesOfClass("V")) {
                    Person person = framedGraph.frame(v, Person.class);
                    System.out.println(String.format("Vertex: %s", person.getFirstName()));
                }

                /* They are NOT going in as Person */
                for (Vertex v : graph.getVerticesOfClass("Person")) {
                    Person person = framedGraph.frame(v, Person.class);
                    System.out.println(String.format("Person: %s", person.getFirstName()));
                }
            } finally {
                graph.shutdown();
            }

        } finally {
            factory.close();
            OServerAdmin admin2 = new OServerAdmin(fullDatabaseName);
            try {
                admin2.connect("root", rootPassword);
                admin2.dropDatabase(database);
            } finally {
                admin2.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found the solution to my problem and I'm posting it here for the next person.

When calling ...

```
FramedGraph<OrientGraph>.addVertex(Object id, Class<F> kind)
```

... the first parameter is used for multiple purposes (Kudos to anyone who can actually find this in the documentation!). The 'kind' parameter here actually has no effect on which class in the database is used to store the data, rather the call should look like

```
framedGraph.addVertex("class:Person", Person.class);
```